# Only expression can be specified when subquery... SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So, I've been working on a loop to get data from each day going back 211 days for a report. 
And I'm getting this error message. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, and although I don't know
why I get this error, I've tried some different things that haven't worked. So I'm asking here really thankful for answers.

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

**My code**

```
create table #ExcelPrint (row int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, Col01 varchar(100), 
Col02 varchar(100), Col03 varchar(100), Col04 varchar(100),Col05 varchar(100))

declare @counter int 
set @counter = 0 
insert into #excelprint (Col01,Col02,Col03) values ('Text','Number', 'Amount')
while @counter > -211 
begin 

insert into #ExcelPrint (Col01,Col02)
select (CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,@counter,GETDATE()),112)),   
(
select TableA.ColA ,sum(colB)
from db.TableA as A 
inner join db.TableB B on B.Col1 = A.Col1
inner join db.TableC C on C.Col1 = B.Col1
where amount = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,@counter,GETDATE()),112)
and A.Col1 = 123
and B = 12
group by ColA.A
)
set @counter = @counter -1 
end

select isnull(Col01,''), Replace(ISNULL(col02,''),'.',','),
Replace(ISNULL(col03,''),'.',',')
,Replace(ISNULL(Col04,''),'.',',') from #ExcelPrint
order by row
drop table #ExcelPrint
```

Comment: in your middle insert clause you trying insert 3 columns (values) - `(CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,@counter,GETDATE()),112))` AND `TableA.ColA` AND `sum(colB)` .... Group by clause is also incorrect `GROUP BY ColA.A` there is no such a column maybe you wanna write `TableA.ColA`

Comment: Does the column you selecting from a sub-query always give one value?

Comment: Why not do this as a single date range grouped by date query instead of a loop with 200 queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know if it's the real syntax of your query but i have some interrogation about it.

1. Why naming db.TableA as A and then in the select do : TableA.xxx do A.xxx
2. In your select you have a ColA and in your where clause a Col1 is it correct and supposed to be different?
3. Still in your where clause, you have a table B, but what is the B = 12?
4. If you wanna have a sum of everything by date, you shoud remove the third column A.ColA or write your query differently. At this moment as you are doing a group by Date, ColA it's splitted :)
5. in the where clause, amount is the date of the "transaction"?

Except these and they are most syntax than logic, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
select (CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,@counter,GETDATE()),112)),   
(
select TableA.ColA ,sum(colB)
from db.TableA as A
```

to

```
select CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,@counter,GETDATE()),112))
,TableA.ColA 
,sum(colB)
from db.TableA as A ...
```

fix the number of column in the insert clause and group on the appropriate column...

Comment: It works now the syntax, but still it dosent get amount for each day.. Guessing something is wrong in my condition

where amount = CONVERT(varchar,Dateadd(DD,@counter,GETDATE()),112)

Comment: if you post the actual code instead of placeholders maybe I can help, but this is pretty messy pseudo code...